# Null a sub-array in a ragged two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays, null

I'm writing an algorithm to solve a crossword puzzle. To reduce processing time (and avoid false catches for words already found), I want to remove the word from the word list after it has been found.

```
char[][] array = new char[2][];
String var = "Hello";
String secondVar = "World";
array[0] = var.toCharArray();
array[1] = secondVar.toCharArray();
//array is now {{H, e, l, l, o},{W, o, r, l, d}}
...
//after word is found, say array[0]
array[0] = null; //throws up NullPointerException
```

How do I null a sub-array in a ragged array? I'd like the final output in the snippet above to be something like `{{},{W, o, r, l, d}}`.

Maybe null is the incorrect thing to do here. I just don't want to index the same word twice once it has been found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make array[0] into an empty array:

```
array[0] = {};
```

Comment: I've tried this, but then NetBeans throws up "illegal start of expression".

Comment: Another approach is to not change the array at all, but create a 2nd array called array2 of Boolean variables and set index 0 to false when word is found.  Then you can write if (!array2[0]).  Alternatively, you can set array[0] = {'^'}; or some other character you know you won't use anywhere else and check for that.

Comment: That's pretty smart, actually. Good call on a boolean array. Thanks!